# XMLHttpRequest Network Connectivity

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, networking, xmlhttprequest

I am making some XMLHttpRequest calls to URLs that require you to be on a certain network. When I run my cordova android application from Eclipse on my device it works fine, but when I package my app up into an apk the application doesn't work. Specifically the XMLHttpRequest gets stuck on pending status. I check my S4 (Android 4.3) Wifi and it is connected to the correct network, but I don't think my phone/application is recognizing it, thus when I make POSTS to the website, I am getting stuck on pending.

What are some ways to fix this? Am I suppose to send a token over that I am already authorized on the network or something?

Comment: Did you change the used ip address or the used hostname?

Comment: `but when I package my app up into an apk the application doesn't work.` Eclipse always makes an apk before installing it on a device where it then runs. So explain first what you mean with and do after "package my app up to an apk".

Comment: When I say I package my app into an apk, I mean that I put it onto a 3rd party enterprise app store, which then gets signed by the proper p12 file and is available for download on my android device. I would also like to add that I am able to make an XMLHttpRequest to Google. My app requires to be connected to our work network, and I believe the application/cordova is not picking up that I am connected to the correct network, even though my wifi says it is, so that is why my POSTS get stuck on pending. Do you how I would go about this?

Comment: If you give them a good working .apk and if you get it signed back and it does not work properly anymore then they molested it. What else?

Comment: I've also tried putting it on our company website for direct download, but it still doesn't work. I still believe its the network issue, where the app is not recognizing that its on the correct network/authenticated.

Comment: How can it be different when it runs on the same device? What difference would it make if Eclipse installs the apk or if you get the apk form Eclipse' bin directory and put it on the device?

Comment: maybe its using the computer's wifi and not the devices? Or somehow signing my application causes something to go wrong?

Comment: Please reread my two latest replies and react to the point on them please.